# Grouped Feature Matrix in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Given large excel data (xlsx, csv, or xls) is it possible to group things and then make it a feature matrix like example below.

Take:

DataFrame1:

```
Name         No.        Comment    
Bob        2123320     Doesn't Matter   
Joe        2832883     Whatever           
John       2139300     Irrelevant        
Bob        2123320     Something          
John       2234903     Regardless
```

DataFrame2:

```
Name          No.          Report    
Bob        2123320         Great 
Joe        2832883         Solid           
John       2139300        Awesome        
Bob        2123320         Good          
John       2234903        Perfect
```

I am basically looking for a way to only select No.'s that have appeared twice for one name and then list out a feature matrix for whether or not a specific Comment/Report appeared for that No. like this:

```
Name Irrelevant Whatever Regardless Awesome Solid Perfect  Irrelevant \
John    1          0       0          1      0     0         0
Name Whatever Regardless Awesome Solid Perfect  
John    0       1         0        0      1
```

So basically it looks for each name, and then for each name it looks to see how many distinct No.'s it has, and for each distinct No.'s, it searches for what the "Comment" and "Report" is and then for some specific Comments 
{Irrelevant, Whatever, Regardless} and Reports {Awesome, Solid, Perfect} it checks if it appears. If it does it outputs a 1 and if not it outputs a 0 in an excel sheet like above. Although Bob appeared twice, since both times he had the same No., it doesn't count and John is the only relevant person. So for John's No. 2139300, he had 1's for irrelevant and awesome and for his No. 2234903 he had 1's for regardless and perfect.

New:

```
.      -----------------------2139300---------------------  2234903----                    
Name Irrelevant Whatever Regardless Awesome Solid Perfect  Irrelevant \
John    1          0       0          1      0     0         0
      --------------------2234903-------------
Name Whatever Regardless Awesome Solid Perfect  
John    0       1         0        0      1
```

Also since the formatting is kind of weird, I meant for it all to be put as one row.

For Clarification: This seems similar, but is different, from a question I asked before. I have created a new question for this question because I've been told to do so.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

First rename 'Reports' column to 'Comment' to align dataframes for concat:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns={'Report':'Comment'})],ignore_index=False)
```

Filter dataframe for names with more that one No. then use `get_dummies`:

```
df_out[df_out.groupby(['Name'])['No.'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1)]\
   .set_index('Name')['Comment'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)\
   .reindex(df_out.Comment, fill_value=0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Comment  Doesn't Matter  Whatever  Irrelevant  Something  Regardless  Great  \
Name                                                                          
John                  0         0           1          0           1      0   

Comment  Solid  Awesome  Good  Perfect  
Name                                    
John         0        1     0        1
```

Comment: This is actually really amazing thank you so much. One quick question: If i just wanted to look for say 3 comments instead of all of them, how would I select some specific comments to look for. Like instead of {Doesn't Matter, Whatever, Irrelevant, Something, Regardless}, I just wanted {Whatever, Irrelevant, Regardless}. Would I have to make a dictionary for this?

Comment: You could just change the reindex part instead of using df.columns which is all columns just use ['Doesn't Matter','Whatever','...]

Comment: Hey. One other question. I wanted to have the data groubed by the No.as well. Like so that all the comments for one No. Would be grouped and then repeat themselves for a different No. I think I mentioned that in the OP as well but I added some clarification.

Comment: @A.Code.1 Can you start a new question with sample data and expected outcome?  It is easier to understand your requirement if you give the expected outcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you so much. I have posted a new question titled: Grouped Feature Matrix #2 - Follow up. Thanks again.